# Visual C++ preprocessor. Acting as if I never #define a variable

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

```
#define CODE

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
#ifdef CODE

std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;

#endif
return 0;
}
```

I'm using visual studio. This code doesn't show "hello", it acts as if I never #define CODE. However, when I #define CODE just after #include "stdafx.h" (and before #include < iostream >), it shows "hello". Thus #include "stdafx.h" is responsible for the problem, but how? (I have no idea what #include "stdafx.h" does)

Comment: Any code lines, that come before `#include "stdafx.h"`, are ignored. `#include "stdafx.h"` should, **always** be the first line in a file. I believe that your compiler should, at least, warn about this.

Comment: If you are at all interested in portability, lose stdafx.h

Comment: But why does it work like this?

Comment: @latedeveloper all the major compilers support precompiled headers at this point, it's more of a question of do you want to deal with the additional build complexity for the speed.

Comment: Why? Imagine that one of the .h files included from `stdafx.h` had an `#ifdef CODE` in it. Suppose you now have two source files that both `#include "stdafx.h"`, and one of them has a `#define CODE` at the top but the other does not. It would no longer be possible to precompile the headers in `stdafx.h`, because they would not all compile the same.

Comment: stdafx.h is likely not buying you anything in this stage of your programming career. I suggest getting rid of it by unchecking "Use precompiled headers" in your projects because it will cause only problems until you have an actual need for it.

Comment: @MGetz Yes, but they do it without introducing artifacts like stdafx.h.

Comment: @latedeveloper fair point, I do have a habit of renaming that `precompiled.hpp` but that's just me

Comment: @chris Turning off precompiled headers would avoid this particular issue, but there is a downside: your code takes longer to compile. Once you know it has to be the first thing in a source file, the precompiled header is very reliable, and your learning experience is improved by the faster compilation.

Comment: @latedeveloper: Which part specifically is non-portable about using a precompiled header? It's just an `#include` after all, right?

Comment: @MichaelGeary The compilation times would add up, yes, until you have a much bigger project where it makes a significant difference on its own. However, you also have to account for the time taking it out for MCVEs of unrelated problems (or having the people helping have to take it out in order to compile on, say, an online compiler). Either way, the time saved or lost looks pretty small, so I opt to take a "one fewer thing to worry about" approach.

Comment: @gigi: Don't you get a compiler warning when you try to build this code? Visual Studio should open the Output window when you build it and there should be a warning there.

Comment: These are the errors :

 warning C4603: 'CODE': macro is not defined or definition is different after precompiled header use

 note: Add macro to precompiled header instead of defining here
 
note: use of precompiled header